# How do I query multiple element types in one query

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft-features

I have Craft Commerce installed, and I wanted to search title against both product title and variant title. I looked up in the database, I noticed that products and variants are of two element types, `Commerce_Product` and `Commerce_Variant`. As far as I know, with `ElementCriteriaModel` you can only query against one element type, like what I have now:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Commerce_Product');
```

Is it possible to query against multiple element types in one db call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a limitation of Craft than Commerce, but it's currently not possible in one query... you'd need to do two and perform some merging/filtering logic.

Consider thumbs-upping/commenting on [this feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/878) which would enable what you're looking for.

Comment: Great, glad to see it's being proposed. Just upped your proposal on github. Thanks.